# Matlab2Tikz Runtime on LaTeX too long

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I am using this thing called `matlab2tikz` which converts MATLAB figures into LaTeX (TikZ) figures. What I have been doing is that I have been using Simulink to do my simulations, and store the data into my workspace and directly plot them into MATLAB figures. When I try to run my code, my LaTeX file with 12 plots (each with about ~50000k data points) will take at least an hour to fully compile the file. I feel that the runtime is slow and unacceptable. I am using TeXStudio with LuaLaTeX. Is there a faster way of doing this, like getting a software faster than TeXStudio, or even getting a GPU?

Comment: I believe this question did not receive much attention. However, plotting 50 million points is unacceptable, for any vector graphics tool. Whether it is pgfplots or something else. In fact, with so much points, you will probably not be able to distinguish two (or more) successive points of your plot. A fist step would be to try and discard data, but that can obviously have consequences on the produced plot. Have a look at this answer of mine which proposes an alternative https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536662/141947

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! Will look into it!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while the question is interesting, it is unlikely one can find a suitable answer to reduce compilation times when handling so much data, susing a LaTeX-only solution.