# Draw invisible axes with visible labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I was fiddling with how to plot raw signals to LaTeX and it turned out that there is no good solution (`tikzexternalize`, R+`kniter`, `matlatb2tikz` are cool but exhaust TeX memory if is really raw data)... Anyway, I decided to go with MATLAB right away and export the plots as PDFs without labels or ticks, which I intended to add/draw on to of the image. Now there's the problem:

**How to draw an invisible frame and tick marks?** 
I need the `tick`s for the `ticklabel`s so `hide axis` is not an option. I feel that this is some `pgfplot style`-thing, which is totally out of my skills.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{constant-plot.png}};
        \begin{axis}[
                scale only axis,
                width = 9.65cm,
                height = 7.93cm,
                xshift=1.84cm,
                yshift=1.47cm,
                xmin=-0.1,
                xmax=1.1,
                ymin=0.05,
                ymax=0.7,
                ytick={0.2,0.4,...,0.6},
                color=green,
                every tick/.style={green}
                ]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I just took a png from [pgfplots.net](http://pgfplots.net/media/tikz/examples/PNG/constant-plot.png).

I have no idea if that is a proper way to link external graphics with Tex-based fonts/labeling but I don't see a different option.

Comment: I doubt that your approach is really feasible if you have more than two plots! If i want to visualize huge datasets i always end up using the combination of `R`, `ggplot2`, `tikzdevice` and `knitr`. The resulting plots integrate well into the general layout of the document. If you mourn about long compile times you have to read the `knitr` documentation more carefully. `knitr` is able to `cache` your chunks. If you use this feature compile times are even reduced compared to a document with lots of inline pgfplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `axis line style={opacity=0}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0cm] at (0,0)
         {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
        \begin{axis}[axis line style={opacity=0},
                scale only axis,
                width = 9.65cm,
                height = 7.93cm,
                xshift=1.84cm,
                yshift=1.47cm,
                xmin=-0.1,
                xmax=1.1,
                ymin=0.05,
                ymax=0.7,
                ytick={0.2,0.4,...,0.6},
                color=green,
                every tick/.style={green}
                ]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, from your description you may be looking for **4.3.7 Using External Graphics as Plot Sources**.

Comment: I don't like the color electric green!!!! :-) There is not a good contrast with the gray background.

Comment: @Sebastiano Then you should be glad that this answer shows how to at least remove the axis lines of this color. ;-)

Comment: In fact I have evaluated it positively immediately...and then I have inserted the comment :-). Obviously it is a personal taste the color.

Comment: yes, exactly! `axis line style={opacity=0},every tick/.style={opacity=0}` did the job =)

Comment: the recommended literature is the [pgfmanual](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)?

Comment: @max No, it is the [pgfplots manual](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer : My answer is more related to the problem of plotting large chunks of data than the technical resolution of the OP. If felt irrelevant, I will happily remove it.**

For my thesis, I had quite a similar issue. I developped an overlay based on the `matlab2tikz` script, unfortunately I can not share it at the moment. However I can help you with the overall strategy I used.

The problem :

- The main issue with raw data is that you tend to overflow `tikz` or `pgfplots` capabilities
- However, you do not want matlab to plot the axis, legends or labels, otherwise you wouldn't ask this question.

The strategy :

- Let matlab do the heavy lifting and create the *raw plot* then remove hide the axis and associated graphics. For this operation, I used the [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig) package, which has the ability to export png plots without most flaws of the matlab printing process.
- Insert the printed image in a `pgfplots` axis using a `graphics` plot

  `\addplot[] graphics[xmin=...,xmax=...,ymin=...,ymax=...] {path/to/your/picture};`

as described in the [`pgfplots manual`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) section 4.3.7 (v1.16)

With my custom script what I basically do is

1. Plot everything
2. Set all axis properties to `manual`
3. Hide the plot of the data and export it with `matlab2tikz`
4. Show the plot of the data, hide the axis and print with `export_fig`
5. Edit the latex document to add the `\addplot graphics`
6. Enjoy

Comment: interesting approach. I'll check this one